# Can I record a video using GLSurfaceView in android?

Tags: android, video, opengl-es, record

Can I record a video using GLSurfaceView in android? I don't want to record the screen info. I want to record using camera but I need to use GLSurfaceView.

Comment: I can't quite figure out what you're after, but take a look at the EncodeAndMuxTest and CameraToMpegTest examples on http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/ .

Comment: Have you managed to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this demo https://github.com/jiangerji/android-screen-recorder
it use intel jar to record glsurfaceview and simple setup.